# Angularjs Validate field on keydown of another field

Tags: angularjs, validation

I have built an angularjs module that provides several form validations other than those that are available out of the box. Among those validations is one called equalTo which takes as a parameter the ngModel value of the field to validate against. The validation is meant to validate that the `$viewValue` of that `ngModel controller`, and the `$viewValue` of the `ngModel controller` that was passed as a parameter are strictly equal. This would be used for password and confirm password fields as an example. This all works, except that I need to be able to validate both fields on keydown of either.

So as I said, all this logic works except that when I call `$validate()` on the other field's controller it always returns undefined and does not seem to validate as I expect. The code is below, but there is a lot of it so I've included a plunk of my problem. You'll notice that when you type anything in for the password initially there is an error because the confirm password does not match. When you type in the confirm password there is no error, but there remains an error on the initial password field unless you go in and retype it.

http://plnkr.co/edit/dIEIuUFMgglOt9uwIDNt?p=preview

**And here is the code**

```
<input type="password" ng-model="password" equal-to="confirmPassword">
<input type="password" ng-model="confirmPassword" equal-to="password">
```

The validation directive looks like this

```
function equalTo(Validator) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            scope: true,
            link: function (scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
                var validator = new Validator(elem,attr,ctrl);
                validator.validate('equalTo');
        }
    }
}
```

And the validator service looks like this

```js
/**
 * Created by rich on 8/14/15.
 *
 * Most of these regex statements were kifed from jquery validation plugin with perhaps a little bit of sugar
 * added to some by yours truly.
 *
 * Thanks to jzaeffer for his efforts.
 * http://jqueryvalidation.org
 * https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation
 */


(function(app, ng) {
    function validator(elementCollector) {
      /**
       * Created by rich on 8/14/15.
       *
       * Most of these regex statements were kifed from jquery validation plugin with perhaps a little bit of sugar
       * added to some by yours truly.
       *
       * Thanks to jzaeffer for his efforts.
       * http://jqueryvalidation.org
       * https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation
       */

      var Validator = function(elem, attr, ctrl) {
        var self = this;
        this.elem = elem;
        this.attr = attr;
        this.ctrl = ctrl;
        this.value = '';
        this.validating = false;
        this.tests = {
          equalTo: function(param) {
            param = self.attr[param];
            var equalityValue = elementCollector.retrieveElementValue(param);
            if (!self.value && !equalityValue) {
              return true
            }
            var isValid = (self.value === equalityValue);
            if (!self.validating) {
              self.validating = true;
              elementCollector.retrieveElementCtrl(param).$validate();
            }
            self.validating = false;
            return isValid
          }
          Validator.prototype.test = function(test) {
            return this.tests[test](test);
          };
          Validator.prototype.validate = function(test) {
            this.configureTest();
            var validator = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
              this.value = viewValue;
              return this.test(test);
            };
            this.ctrl.$validators[test] = validator.bind(this);
          };
          Validator.prototype.configureTest = function() {
            elementCollector.addElement(this.attr.ngModel, this.elem, this.ctrl);
          };
          return Validator;
        }

        app.factory('Validator', validator);
      })(app, angular);
```

And the element collector service looks like this

```js
/**
 * A service to hold all the elements of a Form
 * And their values at any given time
 * To be used with the validations service
 * And validations directives
 */

(function(app, ng) {
  function elementCollector() {
    var elementCollection = {};
    return {
      addElement: function(key, elem, ctrl) {
        elementCollection[key] = {
          element: elem,
          ctrl: ctrl
        };
      },
      setElementValue: function(key, value) {
        elementCollection[key].ctrl.$setViewValue(value);
        elementCollection[key].ctrl.$render();
      },
      retrieveElement: function(key) {
        return elementCollection[key].element;
      },
      retrieveElementValue: function(key) {
        console.log(key);
        return elementCollection[key].ctrl.$viewValue;
      },
      retrieveElementCtrl: function(key) {
        return elementCollection[key].ctrl;
      }
    }
  }

  app.factory('elementCollector', elementCollector);
})(app, angular);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I feel very silly. The problem was not in this code, my solution actually works like it should in the plunk once I added the `$validate()` method. The problem I was having in my code was related to an entirely different error that was causing any javascript after that to stop functioning. Fixed it all up and I'm sorry if I wasted your time. Hopefully the code here helps someone trying to do something similar.